# Why doesn't my function in Seq.map get executed?

Tags: f#

I don't yet understand why my *addLink* function does not get invoked.

I have the following code:

```
let links =   source |> getLinks
let linkIds = links  |> Seq.map addLink // addLink never gets executed
```

At first, I thought that the *links* value was empty.

However, it's not. I verified that it was populated by calling the following:

```
let count = Seq.length links // Returns over 100 items
```

**Note:**

The only way I have been able to execute the function is by first executing:

```
let count  = linkIds |> Seq.length // Call this after performing map
```

Why do I need to do that just for my function to be called?

**Appendix:**

```
let addLink (info:Link) =
    let commandFunc (command: SqlCommand) = 
        command |> addWithValue "@ProfileId"     info.ProfileId
                |> addWithValue "@Title"         info.Title
                |> addWithValue "@Description"   info.Description
                |> addWithValue "@Url"           info.Url
                |> addWithValue "@ContentTypeId" (info.ContentType |> contentTypeToId)
                |> addWithValue "@IsFeatured"    info.IsFeatured
                |> addWithValue "@Created"       DateTime.Now

    commandFunc |> execute connectionString addLinkSql


[<CLIMutable>]
type Link = { 
    Id:            int
    ProfileId:     string
    Title:         String
    Description:   String
    Url:           string
    Topics:        Topic list
    ContentType:   string
    IsFeatured:    bool
}
```

Here's the [source code](https://github.com/bizmonger/Nikeza/blob/master/Server/Nikeza.Server/Command.fs).

Comment: Are you ever using the values in `linkIds`?

Comment: Seq is the same as C#'s IEnumerable, it's not executed until you actually use the results. By calling Seq.length you're forcing it to evaluate the sequence. If you just want to immediately evaulate it you could for example pipe it into Seq.iter ignore.

Comment: lazy evaluation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Seq<'a>` is the same as `IEnumerable<'a>`, which is lazy. This means that each element in the sequence is only evaluated as it's needed. If you want to ensure that side-effects are called, then you could could convert this to a concrete data structure like list by adding `Seq.toList`.

However, it's better and usually possible to write code that performs side-effects separately to code that returns values. You could calculate the linkIds with one function and perform the side effects with another function using `Seq.iter`, which forces full evaluation of the sequence.